# How do I use Shared Preferences in flutter to save user selection after hot restart?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I want to be able to not lose the stroke width and color selected after hot restart. This is how I initialized:

```
  class _DoodleBoardState extends State<DoodleBoard> {
  GlobalKey globalKey = GlobalKey();

  List<TouchPoints> pointsList = [];
  double opacity = 1.0;
  StrokeCap strokeType = StrokeCap.round;
  double strokeWidth = 3.0;
  Color selectedColor = Colors.black;
```

This is what I have tried for the color

```
Future<void> saveColorSelected() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setInt("colorValue", selectedColor);
  }

  Future<int> getColorSelected() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return colorValue = prefs.getInt("colorValue");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Shared Preference it is consist storage. You can reload your application without losing your data.

I write simple app to check it:

```
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.indigo,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int number = DateTime.now().minute;

  Future<void> _saveColorSelected() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setInt("numberValue", number);
    print(number);
  }

  Future<void> _getColorSelected() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    number = prefs.getInt("numberValue") as int;

    print(number);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () => _saveColorSelected(),
              child: const Text('Save number'),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 10),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () => _getColorSelected(),
              child: const Text('Get number'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

After reboot I can get saved value:

> Restarted application in 31ms. 16

Comment: Publish it on GitHub:

Comment: https://github.com/igdmitrov/shared_preferences_app.git